# Composition of linear transformations that preserve angles

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, inner-products

Given two invertible linear transformations T1,T2 in L(V) that preserve angles i.e. $\frac{(T(u), T(v))}
{∥T(u)∥∥T(v)∥}
=
\frac{(u, v)}
{∥u∥∥v∥}
$. How can I show that T1T2 and T<sup>-1</sup> also preserve angles?

From the definition I believe T1,T2 to be isometries but I'm not sure if this helps or is true.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{\langle(T_2\circ T_1)(u), (T_2\circ T_1)(v)\rangle}
{∥(T_2\circ T_1)(u)∥∥(T_2\circ T_1)(v)∥}
=\frac{\langle  T_1(u),  T_1(v)\rangle}
{∥T_1(u)∥∥T_1(v)∥}=
\frac{\langle u, v\rangle }
{∥u∥∥v∥}$$

where in the first equality we have used that $T_2$ preserves angles and in the second equality that $T_1$ preserves angles. Thus $T_2\circ T_1$ preserves angles.

Now, assume $T^{-1}$ exists. Then

$$\frac{\langle u, v\rangle }
{∥u∥∥v∥}=\frac{\langle(T\circ T^{-1})(u), (T\circ T^{-1})(v)\rangle}
{∥(T\circ T^{-1})(u)∥∥(T\circ T^{-1})(v)∥}
=\frac{\langle  T^{-1}(u),  T^{-1}(v)\rangle}
{∥T^{-1}(u)∥∥T^{-1}1(v)∥},$$ which shows that $T^{-1}$ preserves angles.

Finally, note that $T(x)=cx$ preserves angles for any $c\ne 0.$ However it is not an isometry unless $c=\pm 1.$

Comment: Ok Thanks! Seems so simple now.

Comment: You're welcome.